# After Qr code scanning camera crashes windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, zxing, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have application with qr reader. It was developed for WindowsPhone 8.1(winRT), later upgraded to Universal Windows Phone. On WP 8.1 it's working properly. Problem is with windows 10 mobile. Scenario: user is navigate to Scanner Page, it's scanning, decoding qr(using Zxing decode), sending information to server and after success scan is going back to last view. Sometimes when user again navigate to scanner view, a preview is whole gray, and exception is throwed : The text associated with this error code could not be found -System.Exception. It happend on this method:

```
  private async void InitializeQrCode()
    {
        if (_mediaCapture == null)
        {
            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var deviceInformation = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
            var settings = InitCaptureSettings(deviceInformation);


            try
            {
                await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StopAndDisposeCamera();
                scanButton.IsEnabled = false;
                MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("error");
                await msgbox.ShowAsync();
                Xamarin.Insights.Report(ex);
            }

            if (_mediaCapture != null)
            {
                _mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                _mediaCapture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                var torch = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
                if (torch.Supported) torch.Enabled = true;
                SetFocus();
            }
        }
```

exactly on:

```
 await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

After this camera is not working. When i starting default camera app, it displays black screen with information, that i should reboot device and error code: 0xe80110001. After reboot all is ok, while next exception occurs...
Application was tested on lumia 523 which was upgraded from wp 8.1 to wp 10.
Here is whole page code:http://pastebin.com/2aNX9T5m
Any ideas what is wrong? Is it Windows 10 mobile issue ?
Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: are you creating any logs of any sorts that you can read?

Comment: Nope. But on Xamarin insights i had little more information like - System.ExceptionThe text associated with this error code could not be found. The text associated with this error code could not be found.
Raw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Test.Pages.Scanner.<InitializeQrCode>d__15.MoveNext()

Comment: Did you use this [ZXing.Net.Mobile] (https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) library or [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net) package? Did you have another window 10 mobile for testing? Could you please tested it on another phone? I saw you upload the `Scanner` class, are you conveniently to upload the whole reproduce project? You can minimize your project to just reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have only this lumia, but i got information from user(win10 mobile) about app crashing when user was scanning qr code.I reproduced this bug, an put bugged line in try&catch block. I cannot use ZXing.Net.Mobile with MobileBarcodeScanner, because this project was created in Windows RT. So i have to "take photo", and decode it (using  Zxing decode img). I will try to prepare sample with this scanner part.

Comment: Finally, i rebuild my scanner page, using this library https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect. Now its work much better.